# How To Add Pop Form For Submit Review In Magento2 Product Detail Page?

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, frontend

How Can I Add Button For Submit Reviews On Click On This Button Submit Reviews Pop up form Open And User Can Easily Submit The Reviews .

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> **Add this code to your phtml file**

```
<div>
    <button type="button" id="click-me">Click Me!</button>
</div>

<div id="popup-modal" style="display:none;">
    <?php
        echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock(\Magento\Review\Block\Form::class)->setTemplate('Magento_Review::form.phtml')->toHtml();
    ?>
</div>

<script>
    require(
        [
            'jquery',
            'Magento_Ui/js/modal/modal'
        ],
        function(
            $,
            modal
        ) {
            var options = {
                type: 'popup',
                responsive: true,
                innerScroll: true,
                title: 'Your Title title',
                buttons: [{
                    text: $.mage.__('Close'),
                    class: '',
                    click: function () {
                        this.closeModal();
                    }
                }]
            };

            var popup = modal(options, $('#popup-modal'));
            $("#click-me").on('click',function(){ 
                $("#popup-modal").modal("openModal");
            });

        }
    );
</script>
```